# Decoding x11 protocol with wireshark

Tags: x11, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to debug a problem with an X11 Sever and XDCMP. I have captured the traffic with tcpdump and loaded into wireshark.

I am new to wireshark and found this on the web [Tracking XWindow Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213536/tracking-xwindow-protocol) Which seems to indicate that there is a dissector for X11 but I don't get my X11 traffic decoded.I was hoping to get the X11 protocol as per an xtrace ( Note I cannot use xtrace as XDMCP is involved ) I am using wireshark 1.10.6

Comment: note that XDMCP is completely different from X11 protocol and uses different ports - http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libXdmcp/xdmcp.html

Comment: XDMCP is not a problem that part is working and opening up the X Server ports, hence no need to trace

Answer (score 0):

> Which seems to indicate that there is a dissector for X11

There is.

> but I don't get my X11 traffic decoded.

If you captured X traffic, there might be a bug or some other issue.  Please file a bug on [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org/), and attach a network trace to the bug, so we can try to debug it.

Comment: Thanks For anybody else passing the reported bug is at https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11869

Comment: ...and the issue is that Wireshark only treats traffic to or from ports 6000 through 6002 as X11 traffic, but X11 traffic can, and does, use other ports, and the X11 traffic in your capture was on another port, so you needed to do a "Decode As" operation.

Answer (score 0):

Was not aware that the correct way to drive wireshark is to select the traffic then right click on the mouse, select decode as, then X11.